# Focus a Control Inside a List of Child Components in Vue

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, vue-component

So I have a vue template that renders a list of child components.

The goal is to, when running `addIngredient()` in my parent, I want to go to the child component that represents the last item in the `ingredientList` array used in my for loop and focus on the `amount` input in the `ingredient record` child component

**parent**

```js
<template>
  <div> 
    <ingredient-record 
      v-for="(ingredient, index) in ingredientList" 
      :index="index"
      :key="index"
      :id="`ingredient-record${index}`"
      :ingredient="ingredient" 
      @enterPressed="enterPressed"
      @removeIngredient="removeIngredient" />
    <div class="mt-2">
      <button
        @click="addIngredient()"
        type="button"
        class="w-full sm:w-auto flex items-center justify-center px-3 sm:px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 text-sm leading-5 font-medium rounded-md text-gray-700 bg-white hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 active:text-gray-800 active:bg-gray-50 active:text-gray-800 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
      >
        <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="w-5 h-5">
          <path
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zm1-11a1 1 0 10-2 0v2H7a1 1 0 100 2h2v2a1 1 0 102 0v-2h2a1 1 0 100-2h-2V7z"
            clip-rule="evenodd"
          />
        </svg>
        <p class="pl-2">Add Ingredient</p>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import IngredientRecord from "@/components/recipe/IngredientRecord.vue";
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  props: ["ingredientList"],
  components: {
    IngredientRecord
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    addIngredient() {
      this.$props.ingredientList.push({});

      let maxKey = this.$props.ingredientList.length;
      console.log(maxKey);

      let label = `ingredient-record${maxKey}`;
      console.log(label);

      this.$emit("updateIngredients", this.$props.ingredientList);
    },
    removeIngredient(ingredientIndex) {
      this.$props.ingredientList.splice(ingredientIndex, 1);
      this.$emit("updateIngredients", this.$props.ingredientList);
    },
    enterPressed(rowIsEmpty){
      if(rowIsEmpty){
        this.$emit("enterPressed");
      }
      else{
        this.addIngredient();
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**child component (ingredient record)**

```js
<template>
  <div class="grid grid-cols-16 gap-1">
    <label for="amount" class="sr-only">amount</label>
    <input
      id="amount"
      placeholder="1" 
      v-model="ingredient.amount"
      class="col-span-2 py-2 px-2 mt-1 form-input block w-full sm:text-sm sm:leading-5 lg:py-1 rounded-md truncate shadow-sm"
    />
    <label for="unit" class="sr-only">unit</label>
    <input
      id="unit"
      placeholder="cup" 
      v-model="ingredient.unit"
      class="col-span-5 py-2 px-2 mt-1 form-input block w-full sm:text-sm sm:leading-5 lg:py-1 rounded-md truncate shadow-sm"
    />
    <label for="name" class="sr-only">name</label>
    <input
      id="name"
      placeholder="all purpose flour" 
      v-model="ingredient.name"
      @keyup.enter="enterPressed()"
      class="col-span-8 py-2 px-2 mt-1 form-input block w-full sm:text-sm sm:leading-5 lg:py-1 rounded-md truncate shadow-sm"
    />
    <button
      @click="removeIngredient(ingredient)"
      type="button"
      class="col-span-1 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-500 rounded hover:text-gray-500 focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 active:text-gray-800 active:bg-gray-50 active:text-gray-800 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
    >
      <svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" >
        <path d="M19 7l-.867 12.142A2 2 0 0116.138 21H7.862a2 2 0 01-1.995-1.858L5 7m5 4v6m4-6v6m1-10V4a1 1 0 00-1-1h-4a1 1 0 00-1 1v3M4 7h16"/>
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import isEmpty from "lodash/isEmpty"

export default {
  props: ["ingredient", "id"],
  computed: {
    rowEmpty() {
      return isEmpty(this.$props.ingredient);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    removeIngredient() {
      this.$emit("removeIngredient", this.$props.id);
    },
    enterPressed() {
      this.$emit("enterPressed", this.rowEmpty);
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: This may not answer the question, but why are you referencing the props with `$props` rather than the immediate `this.{propName}`? Also, you shouldn't mutate props in the first place.

Comment: just an oversight. don't see where i'm mutating the props though? just emitting them

Comment: This line does it: `this.$props.ingredientList.push({});`, as well as `.splice()`. If you need to mutate it anyway, consider `.sync`-ing it across the components instead.

Comment: So, what is it that's hindering you from achieving this desired action? Could you add the relevant code (that didn't work for you)?

Comment: not sure what other code would be applicable. it pushes the new array just fine, but i'm trying to focus the input in the next component once it's added. looking into options with refs right now, but not sure of the syntax yet

Comment: I (mostly) have it. if you do something like this `this.$refs.ingredientList[1].$refs.amount.focus()` with a ref on the call of the child component as well as on the inputs in the child component, it works great. Just need to feed in the index dynamically now. will post an answer when i'm allowed in 2 days

Comment: something like this `let maxKey = this.ingredientList.length - 1; this.$refs.ingredientList[maxKey].$refs.amount.focus();` should work, but the new child component is undefined, i'm assuming because it isn't rendered yet. i know this works because if you do - 2, it will select the prior child on add

Comment: Or, you could delegate the input-focusing to the target children themselves. Regarding children components going undefined when referenced during the rendering, [`Vue.nextTick`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) usually fixes it.

Comment: yup, was just googling the syntax for it! works: `let maxKey = this.ingredientList.length - 1; this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.ingredientList[maxKey].$refs.amount.focus());`. considering moving it to child, but wanted to at least POC here. cheers for the brainstorm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here for accessing components like this is to use refs. When accessing them in a loop, just use the index of the array. As far as the focus state goes, you'll need to use `nextTick()` to make sure the child component has rendered

**parent**

```js
<template>
  <div> 
    <ingredient-record 
      v-for="(ingredient, index) in ingredientList" 
      :index="index"
      :key="index"
      :id="`ingredient-record${index}`"
      :ingredient="ingredient" 
      ref="ingredientList"
      @enterPressed="enterPressed"
      @removeIngredient="removeIngredient" />
    <div class="mt-2">
      <button
        @click="addIngredient()"
        type="button"
        class="w-full sm:w-auto flex items-center justify-center px-3 sm:px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 text-sm leading-5 font-medium rounded-md text-gray-700 bg-white hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 active:text-gray-800 active:bg-gray-50 active:text-gray-800 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
      >
        <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="w-5 h-5">
          <path
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zm1-11a1 1 0 10-2 0v2H7a1 1 0 100 2h2v2a1 1 0 102 0v-2h2a1 1 0 100-2h-2V7z"
            clip-rule="evenodd"
          />
        </svg>
        <p class="pl-2">Add Ingredient</p>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import IngredientRecord from "@/components/recipe/IngredientRecord.vue";
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  props: ["ingredientList"],
  components: {
    IngredientRecord
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    addIngredient() {
      this.ingredientList.push({});

      this.$emit("updateIngredients", this.ingredientList);

      let maxKey = this.ingredientList.length - 1;
      this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.ingredientList[maxKey].$refs.amount.focus());
    },
    removeIngredient(ingredientIndex) {
      this.ingredientList.splice(ingredientIndex, 1);
      this.$emit("updateIngredients", this.ingredientList);
    },
    enterPressed(rowIsEmpty){
      if(rowIsEmpty){
        this.$emit("enterPressed");
      }
      else{
        this.addIngredient();
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**child**

```js
<template>
  <div class="grid grid-cols-16 gap-1">
    <label for="amount" class="sr-only">amount</label>
    <input
      id="amount"
      ref="amount"
      placeholder="1" 
      v-model="ingredient.amount"
      class="col-span-2 py-2 px-2 mt-1 form-input block w-full sm:text-sm sm:leading-5 lg:py-1 rounded-md truncate shadow-sm"
    />
    <label for="unit" class="sr-only">unit</label>
    <input
      id="unit"
      ref="unit"
      placeholder="cup" 
      v-model="ingredient.unit"
      class="col-span-5 py-2 px-2 mt-1 form-input block w-full sm:text-sm sm:leading-5 lg:py-1 rounded-md truncate shadow-sm"
    />
    <label for="name" class="sr-only">name</label>
    <input
      id="name"
      ref="name"
      placeholder="all purpose flour" 
      v-model="ingredient.name"
      @keyup.enter="enterPressed()"
      class="col-span-8 py-2 px-2 mt-1 form-input block w-full sm:text-sm sm:leading-5 lg:py-1 rounded-md truncate shadow-sm"
    />
    <button
      @click="removeIngredient(ingredient)"
      type="button"
      class="col-span-1 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-500 rounded hover:text-gray-500 focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 active:text-gray-800 active:bg-gray-50 active:text-gray-800 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
    >
      <svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" >
        <path d="M19 7l-.867 12.142A2 2 0 0116.138 21H7.862a2 2 0 01-1.995-1.858L5 7m5 4v6m4-6v6m1-10V4a1 1 0 00-1-1h-4a1 1 0 00-1 1v3M4 7h16"/>
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import isEmpty from "lodash/isEmpty"

export default {
  props: ["ingredient", "id"],
  computed: {
    rowEmpty() {
      return isEmpty(this.ingredient);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    removeIngredient() {
      this.$emit("removeIngredient", this.id);
    },
    enterPressed() {
      this.$emit("enterPressed", this.rowEmpty);
    },
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```